# How to get a count of objects in a Queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I have a model which which has fields like:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    car_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This model has a lot of duplicate values too, I would like distinct to be shown

The queryset gives an output like:

```
<QuerySet [{'car_name': 'Audi', 'car_color': 'Red'}, {car_name': 'BMW', 'car_color': 'white'}]>
```

[edit]I want my output Queryset to have another field, which is like a counter for the ouput. If I get two objects out of the query, then a field called `ordinal_count` also be sent in queryset.

**The output I am looking for example:**

```
<QuerySet [{'car_name': 'Audi', 'car_color': 'Red', 'ordinal_count': 1}, {car_name': 'BMW', 'car_color': 'white', 'ordinal_count': 2}, {car_name': 'Jaguar', 'car_color': 'olive green', 'ordinal_count': 3}]>
```

This is the query which I wrote:

```
op = (Vehicle.objects.annotate(ordinal_count=Count("car_name", distinct="car_name")).filter(car_color='white', list_display=True).values("car_name","car_color", "ordinal_count"))
```

This is not giving me the desired input and is also messing up the filter. Should I even be using annotate?

Then I also wrote another query but it fails to run:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

Query is:

```
count = Vehicle.objects.filter(car_color='white', list_display=True).distinct(
      "car_name").annotate(ordinal_count=Count("car_name")).values_list(
        "car_name","car_color", "ordinal_count")
```

[edit 1] Tried the solution by @trigo, but it gives me an output like(where ordinal_count remains 2). I want `ordinal_count` to be like a counter for the objects which come in a queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'car_name': 'Audi', 'car_color': 'Red', 'ordinal_count': 2}, {car_name': 'BMW', 'car_color': 'white', 'ordinal_count': 2}, {car_name': 'Jaguar', 'car_color': 'olive green', 'ordinal_count': 2}]>
```

**[Update]**:

```
qs = (
        Vehicle.objects.filter(car_color="white", list_display=True)
        .distinct("car_name")
        .annotate(ordinal_count=Window(expression=RowNumber(), partition_by=None))
        .values("slug", "car_name", "car_color","ordinal_count")
    ).order_by('car_name')
```

the only issue here is annotate works before filtering. So the ordinal_count is messing up. Is there a way to be able to filter first?

**edit3**

Suppose there are 5 objects in total and I have said I want all white color cars, with distinct car_name.

The output after applying filter, it seems like annotation happens after filter, because of the jumbled up ordinal_count:

```
<QuerySet [{'car_name': 'Audi', 'car_color': 'white', 'ordinal_count': 3}, {car_name': 'BMW', 'car_color': 'white', 'ordinal_count': 2}, {car_name': 'Jaguar', 'car_color': 'white', 'ordinal_count': 5}]>
```

Comment: Do you want distinct  (car_name, car_color together) count, or order of query

Comment: Can you add example of what output you are getting before and after filter?

Comment: @JavohirElmurodov No I just want distinct car_name

Comment: @ruddra Hey I have given examples under edit3

Answer (score 1):

[Assumption] : By duplicate you mean only on the attribute "car_name". However, if you mean duplicate on "car_name" and "color" combined, below queryset shall not work. Let me know if this is the case, shall provide other solution for it.

The below queryset shall give you your desired output.

```
Vehicle.objects.filter().values("car_name").annotate(ordinal_count=Count("id")).order_by("car_name")
```

[Note]: If your database is PostgreSQL, you can use distinct() however in other database this is hacky way to achieve the same.

In complex queries, you would need to write a sql query directly.

[EDIT 1]
Ok, so basically ordinal_count is NOT the number of times the car_name has occurred but just the counter. Right?
As per your expected output which you provided, i.e.

```
<QuerySet [{'car_name': 'Audi', 'car_color': 'Red', 'ordinal_count': 1}, {car_name': 'BMW', 'car_color': 'white', 'ordinal_count': 2}, {car_name': 'Jaguar', 'car_color': 'olive green', 'ordinal_count': 3}]>
```

As per your sample output above, by ordinal_count you only mean the counter (i.e.) index of the array + 1 ? That is the only conclusion I can reach as per your example. For this you may not need to annotate at all.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. But the ordinal_count value remains equal to 2. I want it to increase with the count of objects which come in the query.

Comment: Can you modify your question slightly and put some examples ?

Comment: Hey modified the question, gave examples too

Comment: i think its a right solution as per your ask, i tried. @chixcy

Comment: @HemalPatel I want the ordinal_count to act like a counter. If a queryset has 5 objects then the ordinal_count should go from 1 to 5. Basically, like an index, but dynamically being set. Therefore, the answer given doesn't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a complete example but there is a Window expression (inside you can use RowNumber()) available in django models that could help you:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

query = Vehicle.objects.values(...).annotate(row_number=Window(expression=RowNumber()))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Window, F

Vehicle.objects.distinct('car_name').annotate(ordinal_count=Window(
    expression=Count("id"),
    partition_by=[F("car_name")]
)).values(
    car_name,
    car_color,
    ordinal_count
).order_by('ordinal_count')
```

This query results following
`[{"car_name": "BMW", "car_color": "black", "ordinal_count": 5}...]`

Comment: There is also a filter which is missing in this

Comment: yes apply filter before distinct

Comment: I did do that. Could you check the question I updated the query there. But the issue is annotation runs before the filter.